# How to add up/merge the rows if the values of certain column repeats

Tags: r

Here is my df

```
head(B_chain)
   V1   V2       V4    V5       V6       n
27 ARG 109       NH1   DA      133       1 
39 TYR  86       CD2   DA      133       2
40 TYR  86       CE2   DA      133       3
56 TYR 110       CD1   DA      133       1
58 TYR 110       CE1   DA      133       4
60 TYR 110       CZ    DA      133       2
```

I want to add up the frequency of those rows which repeats

such as see lines 39 and 40

in this we have columns V2 86 and V6 133

whenever column V2 and Column V6 values repeat in the data frame merge / add up those rows and  column V4 should be like CD2, CE2

and last column "n"  add the frequencies of both 2+3=5

I need output like this

```
   V1   V2       V4              V5     V6         n
27 ARG 109       NH1             DA     133        1 
39 TYR  86       CD2,CE2         DA     133        5
56 TYR 110       CD1             DA     133        1
58 TYR 110       CE1             DA     133        4
60 TYR 110       CZ              DA     133        2
```

please guide thanks.

Comment: What about the last three rows? Why they have not been merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear why the last 3 rows shouldn't be one group?
However here is a tidyverse `dplyr` solution.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(V1, V2, V5, V6) %>%
  summarise(
    V4 = paste(V4, collapse = ","),
    n = sum(n)
  ) %>%
  select(
    V1, V2, V4, V5, V6, n
  )
```

Comment: It works thank you for your early response. Yes, I also want to apply this to the last 3 lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr solution works fine for me, Can we apply the same code with some exceptions such as

If column V4 has O, OH then those rows remain untouched (not added) as we did earlier.

```
head(B_chain)
   V1   V2       V4    V5       V6       n
27 ARG 109       NH1   DA      133       1 
39 TYR 110       CD2   DA      133       2
40 TYR 110       CE2   DA      133       3
56 TYR 110       OH    DA      133       1
58 TYR 110       O     DA      133       4
```

out put like this

```
   V1   V2       V4        V5       V6       n
27 ARG 109       NH1       DA      133       1 
39 TYR 110       CD2,CE2   DA      133       5
56 TYR 110       OH        DA      133       1
58 TYR 110       O         DA      133       4
```

OH O contain rows remain as it is.

Thanks